# TikZ figure inside equation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations

I was wondering if it is possible to have a TikZ graphic inside an equation, 
to produce something similar to [image: TikZ and equations]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does those symbols represent? I guess that lifting weight and nose piercing are not the correct answers. :)

Comment: The first symbol stands for a direct edge between to vertices and the second one for the case of two vertices being connected along an alternative path... :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\straight{\tikz[baseline=.1ex]{
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt) coordinate (A);
\fill (0,1.5ex) circle (1pt) coordinate (B);
\draw (A)--(B);}
}

\def\curved{\tikz[baseline=.1ex]{
\fill (0,0) circle (1pt) coordinate (A);
\fill (0,1.5ex) circle (1pt) coordinate (B);
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (.7ex, 1.5ex);
\draw (A) .. controls +(1ex,-1ex) and +(1ex, 1ex) .. (B);}%
}

\begin{document}

\[ P(\straight) + P(\curved) = p \]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

The tricky part is to get right the alignment. The vertical alignment can be controled with the option `baseline` of `\tikz`, which specifies the depth of the resulting glyph (the amount of it that protrudes below the base line). The horizontal alignment can be adjusted via `\useasboundingbox`, as in the curved example, which allows us to specify the size that TeX should leave for that glyph. The actual glyph actually is a bit bigger, but forcing tex to see it as smaller causes the right parenthesys to be placed closer.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. I'll try to familiarise myself with the influence of baseline and useasboundingbox.

Answer (score 4):

A starter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[ y=\tikz\draw (0,0)--(0,1); \, x \]

\end{document}
```