# Problem with TikZ in math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to add in some TikZ pictures as math symbols to represent some knot equations. Hence, I've created a couple of commands to create these images quickly.

```
\newcommand{\KA}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [line width=1.5]    (100.4,110.6) .. controls (119.4,71.1) and (119.4,71.1) .. (99.9,30.6) ;
\draw [line width=1.5]    (150.9,110.1) .. controls (131.9,70.1) and (130.9,70.1) .. (150.4,30.1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\KB}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [line width=1.5]    (207.02,45.05) .. controls (246.62,63.85) and (246.62,63.85) .. (287.02,44.15) ;
\draw [line width=1.5]    (207.78,95.55) .. controls (247.68,76.35) and (247.68,75.35) .. (287.78,94.65) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then, I attempt to use this in a document. In a regular environment, this is fine. However, inside mathmode, where I need it, it throws an error. For something simple like:

```
$$
\KA + \KB
$$
```

, I get the error: [image]

Then, I attempted to use \mathord{} around each command. Still I get the error.

Here is the MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\KA}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [line width=1.5]    (100.4,110.6) .. controls (119.4,71.1) and (119.4,71.1) .. (99.9,30.6) ;
\draw [line width=1.5]    (150.9,110.1) .. controls (131.9,70.1) and (130.9,70.1) .. (150.4,30.1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\KB}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [line width=1.5]    (207.02,45.05) .. controls (246.62,63.85) and (246.62,63.85) .. (287.02,44.15) ;
\draw [line width=1.5]    (207.78,95.55) .. controls (247.68,76.35) and (247.68,75.35) .. (287.78,94.65) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    $$\KA+\KB$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your newcommands are coded to require a parameter. Just get rid of the `[1]` after `{\KA}` and `{\KB}`. Also, you should use `\[ .. \]` instead of `$$ .. $$`. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/125871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem of **Adding tikz plot in equation** (maybe a *duplicate*).
This can be done by modify the `newcommand` to fit for equation.

> Reference: [TikZ figure inside equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/tikz-figure-inside-equation)

Instead of using the `tikzpicture` environment, you can just use `\tikz` command.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\KA}{\raisebox{-0.3mm}{
\tikz[x=0.075pt,y=0.075pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]{
\draw [line width=0.3]    (100.4,110.6) .. controls (119.4,71.1) and (119.4,71.1) .. (99.9,30.6) ;
\draw [line width=0.3]    (150.9,110.1) .. controls (131.9,70.1) and (130.9,70.1) .. (150.4,30.1);}}
}

\newcommand{\KB}{
\tikz[x=0.075pt,y=0.075pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]{
\draw [line width=0.3]    (207.02,45.05) .. controls (246.62,63.85) and (246.62,63.85) .. (287.02,44.15) ;
\draw [line width=0.3]    (207.78,95.55) .. controls (247.68,76.35) and (247.68,75.35) .. (287.78,94.65) ;}
}

\begin{document}
    % make it larger to see (x10)
    \scalebox{10}{
        $$\KA+\KB$$
    }
\end{document}
```

So far, no error is produced, but the size of the plot should be adjusted. I made some changes and now it looked like:
[image: Result]

#### EDIT

As [Sandy G](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/125871/sandy-g) pointed out, the use of `tikzpicture` is no problem. It is just my habit to use the simple `\tikz` command in maths equation.

Comment: FYI, the issue has nothing to do with the command `\tikz`. In LaTeX you can use `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` interchangeably with `\tikz{ ... }`.

Comment: @SandyG Yes indeed, a matter of habit  In maths equation I have the preference of using `\tikz` command.